# Getting Source-Dest IP and PORT data for traffic monitoring in ONOS

Tags: sdn, openflow, onos

I am trying to implement a monitoring system using ONOS. I am able to collect the port delta statistics from them using port_stat_changed listener.
In the flow statistics, I get the flow entry, which has selection criterion. This criterion only has only Ethernet information. Is there any way to identify the Source and Destination IP address and Port using ONOS. Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source and destination IP and MAC if they are not in the Switch's rules can be accessed by the application by taking this information from the packets. If your application does not have access to the packages, I do not think the Switches store this kind of information. In case, then, you're going to have to develop a solution by putting a rule in the Switch to pick up that data.